# How to get dropdownlist_selectedindexchange to trigger first

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a webForms aspx page, and in the code behind, I have a breakpoint set to a dropdownList box "AdminCategory". On this page, also is a UserControl (.ascx). The UserControl has another dropdownlistbox (ucEmployee).

In the codebehind of my Dashboard.aspx.vb, my code block is

```
Protected Sub ddlAdminCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As 
EventArgs)
Try
      .....
End Sub
```

In the codebehind of my ucEmployee.ascx.vb, my code block is

```
Private Sub ucEmployee_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Me.Load
Try
      .....
End Sub
```

When I change the dropdownlist item of AminCategory, the ucEmplyee_Load event is fired first.
I need the ddlAdminCategory to be triggered first, and then the ucEmployee_Load to be triggered.

How do I ensure that ddlAdminCategory_SelectedIndexChanged is triggered first?

Answer (score 0):

By using `IsPostBack` you can find request is first time or second time

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        ' More coding will go here.
        '--------------------------
    End If
```

Comment: the above answer did not help.